# Javascript function echo message after redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

**HTML form:**

```
<form action="/uploads.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time(); ?>
        $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'formData'     : {
        'timestamp' : '<?php echo time();?>',
        'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
        'user_dir'  : '<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>'
    },
    'swf'      : '/includes/configuration/uploads.swf',
    'uploader' : '/includes/configuration/uploads.php'
        });
        });
    </script>
    <p><small>Only JPEG, GIF, PNG and PDF allowed<br />
    Maximum <strong>6</strong> documents, <strong>4MB</strong> each one
    </small>
    </p>
    </span>
</form>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
//Some code here
if(c.inArray("onUploadSuccess",g.overrideEvents)<0){c("#"+f.id).find(".data").html(" - Complete");}
//Some code here
```

I want to echo a message after the user upload a picture on the same page.

It shows a message "- Complete", after the picture is uploaded but it shows the message small near uploading field.

I do not want to use any **`alert("Any text here");`** code. I want the message to be displayed in the same page, like the message "-Complete", but in other place on the webpage. Is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

***After some tests, I found the solution:***

**I addeed somewhere in HTML:**

```
<div id="message" style="position: relative; width: 600px; left: 20%; margin-top: 5px;"><?php echo output_message($message); ?></div>
```

**And in Javascript:**

```
//Some code here
if(c.inArray("onUploadSuccess",g.overrideEvents)<0){c("#"+f.id).find(".data").html(" - Complete");
$("#message").html("<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>Message Here</div>");           
}
//Some code here
```

I really hope this help others in trying to echo a message with javascript.